# STR_TO DATE not quite working

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
Select *,  STR_TO_DATE(l.act_detail,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS callback_date, DATE_FORMAT(l.act_date , '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i' ) as activity_date                   
            from lead_activity as l 
            join rawdata as r on (r.phone=l.phone) && (r.year_make=l.year_make) && (r.model=l.make)   
            where l.sp_id=".$_SESSION['user']['sp_id']." 
            and ((callback_date>='$date1' ) && (callback_date<= '$date2')) 
             and l.act_name='SCB'
            ORDER BY  l.act_date DESC
```

i am trying to use text filed ocnverted to datetime and do a  where on that column ?  any ideas ? act_detail = 2012-10-29 05:10:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should not use `callback_date` because it is an alias, you can't use it in `where` clause
- you cannot use `&&` but instead `AND`

query,

```
SELECT .....
FROM ....
WHERE  l.sp_id= 'sessionValue' AND
       (STR_TO_DATE(l.act_detail,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= '$date1') AND
       (STR_TO_DATE(l.act_detail,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') <= '$date2') .....
```